# Hide an application from Running Apps on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am developing an iOS app and I need it to be hidden from Running Apps so that User can't neither stop it nor Un-install it.

Searching all forums and threads so far has lead to the result that is impossible (unless Jailbreaking the device, which is not an option in my case).

the aim is to have an app that monitor user actions for Parental control (excuse me for Confidential reasons I can't give further details)

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: So you basically want to know how to write malware?

Comment: Even if possible, no one would release it on a public forum.

Comment: Nop the aim is to have an app that monitor user actions for Parental control (excuse me for Confidential reasons I can't give further details)

Comment: Good luck trying to pass Apple's store review process.

Comment: app will not be put on apple's public store

Comment: @a.boussema Have you researched Parental Gates?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It is impossible unless Jailbreaking the device.